# I have installed android studio on linux mint but I don't know where it is?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, sdk, android-studio

I have installed android studio on linux mint and I run it for the first time and worked fine.But, then I close it and now I don't know where it is. I tried to find it from menu but it is not there. I want to set it in menu, like other software are.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually installed in your home directory. In a terminal, use the following command to find a file that is in the base of the installation directory:

```
locate "SDK Readme.txt"
```

If that doesn't find it, your file index database may be out of date; update that with:

```
sudo updatedb
```

If for whatever reason `locate` is not working on your system, use find instead:

```
find $HOME -name "SDK Readme.txt"
```

You might want to add the path, once found, to your .bashrc file.
Depending on what you are using from the SDK, you will likely want these two entries, with $BASE= the directory you found SDK Readme.txt in
$BASE/tools
$BASE/platform-tools

Add a line in .bashrc like this (I replaced $BASE with the actual location of the SDK on my machine):

```
export PATH=$PATH":$HOME/Android/Sdk/tools:$HOME/Android/Sdk/platform-tools"
```

Update:

- For all of these steps you'll need the path to the executable(s). This includes in part the location you found SDK Readme.txt, which we'll call the base directory. As an example, if you found that file in `/home/ranjeet/Android/Sdk/` then that will be the base directory. There are two primary subdirectories that contain the programs for the Android SDK. The primary one that you will likely want is android, which is the SDK manager, and using that base example, it's path will be: `/home/ranjeet/Android/Sdk/tools/android`
- You can add a program to the 'start' menu in Mint by following the directions at this link, assuming you are you using the default desktop. Use the path to android from above. [community.linuxmint.com](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1504)
- It might be easier (since you are new to linux) to simply add a desktop shortcut. Right click on the desktop, and select 'Create New Shortcut'.

  - In the command window, use the path to android. 'Type' should be application, name can be anything, e.g. 'Android SDK Manager', and comment can be anything including blank. Click OK, and you'll have a desktop shortcut.
- You will likely want to launch many of these programs from the command line (especially if interfacing with an android device using adb or fastboot). To make that easier, you need to add a couple lines to your environmental config file for bash called .bashrc. Using a text editor, e.g. vi or gedit, edit .bashrc by (replace vi with whatever text editor you are using) `vi ~/.bashrc`.     Go to the bottom of the .bashrc file, and add the line:
  `export PATH=$PATH":/home/ranjeet/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/ranjeet/Android/Sdk/platform-tools"`
  Save and close the file, and type `source ~/.bashrc` at the command prompt. You can now run all the android SDK programs in those two directories from the command line regardless of where you are in the filesystem since they are on your 'path'.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help. I am new to linux that why I don't understand what should do after typing that command. It showed path of sdk readme.txt file and how  can I set it in menu as other software.